# Getting Error while trying to Link host strings to simulator SDK (Linphone)

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, compilation, linphone

I am trying to compile linphone source code downloaded from [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone).

I am following the steps defined [here](http://www.successmonkey.co.nz/blog/building-linphone-for-ios)..

The problem is I am getting error while trying to **Link host strings to simulator SDK** on terminal. Its showing following error

> "***No Such file or directory***."

[image: Here is screenshot of my terminal...]

What should I do to solve this problem? Is there any alternate to Link host strings to simulator SDK ?

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial is obsolete. You don't need the `string` symlink anymore, so you should follow the README instead from the git repository and it should work. Basically:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone
cd linphone-iphone
./prepare.py # this might raise some errors "Please install XXX program. Do that."
make
open linphone.xcodeproj
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it and will let you know.

Comment: I am trying to clone repository using 
**git clone https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone** but I am getting error 
**Mac-mini:linphone krishna$ git clone https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone
Cloning into 'linphone-iphone'...
remote: Counting objects: 36159, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806s/s        
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed**

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla: your network connection might be too unstable. Try again with `git clone --recursive https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone --depth 1`, or try on another network.

Comment: HI @bagage, Its failing again and again. Can you please provide me compiled code of it which also supports 64 bit arch ?

Comment: Sorry but no. You have to deal with that error by yourself and is unrelated to the question you asked here. Again, use another network connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Finally I did it..  I am accepting your answer.. It helped me a lot.. Thanks..(y)